# Type Mismatch Error when referencing Folder with PickFolder

Tags: vba, outlook, type-mismatch

The following is supposed to launch a popup folder picker, and then move the current item to the selected folder.

```
 Sub MoveItems()
     Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
     Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
     Dim mySubFolder As Outlook.Folder
     Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
     Dim myItem As Object

     Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
     Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
     Set mySubFolder = myNameSpace.PickFolder
     Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders(mySubFolder)
     Set myItem = GetCurrentItem()

     myItem.Move myDestFolder

End Sub
```

I am getting a Type Mismatch on the line

```
Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders(mySubFolder)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*That line should be **`Set myDestFolder = mySubFolder`***

You may wanna also use `If mySubFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` just in case user decides to cancel the `myNameSpace.PickFolder` so you don't get `run-time error`

```
Option Explicit
Sub MoveItems()
     Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
     Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
     Dim mySubFolder As Outlook.Folder
     Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
     Dim myItem As Object

     Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
     Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
     Set mySubFolder = myNameSpace.PickFolder

    If mySubFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

     Set myDestFolder = mySubFolder
     Set myItem = GetCurrentItem()

     myItem.Move myDestFolder

End Sub

Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application

    Set objApp = Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        Case "Inspector"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End Select

    Set objApp = Nothing
End Function
```

---

***[IsNothing Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5adx7fxz(v=vs.90).aspx)***

> *<sub>**[IsNothing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5adx7fxz(v=vs.90).aspx)** returns True if the expression represents an object variable that currently has no object assigned to it; otherwise, it returns False.</sub>*

Comment: Interesting, so with the picker there is no need to select the base folder with myInbox.   huh.  If I adapted to moving from subfolder to subfolder, would I still need the .parent stuff?  I bet not.   Thanks!!

Comment: You are moving Items from inbox, you can change that with picker from and to picker and it should work